# Mail listener on nodejs not disconnecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nightwatch.js

I'm currently using [mail-listener5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener5) package to assert the number of emails in the Inbox of an email address.

My test framework is nightwatchjs.

Currently, my command script to get the number of emails from the email address inbox (titled getInboxEmails) is;

```
var  {MailListener}  = require('mail-listener5');

exports.command = function() {
    this.perform(function(done) {
        var mailListener = new MailListener({
            username: '#########@outlook.com',
            password: '#########',
            host: 'imap-mail.outlook.com',
            port: 993,
            tls: true,
            connTimeout: 10000,
            authTimeout: 5000,
            tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
            mailbox: 'Inbox', 
            searchFilter: ['ALL'], 
            markSeen: true,
            fetchUnreadOnStart: false,
            attachments: false,
        });

        mailListener.start();

        mailListener.on('server:connected', function() {});

        mailListener.on('mailbox', function(mailbox) {
            var totalInboxMessages = (mailbox.messages.total);
            console.log('Total number of Inbox emails: ', totalInboxMessages);
        });

        //  mailListener.on('server:disconnected', function() {
        //  });

       //  mailListener.stop();
    done();
    });
};
```

And my nightwatchjs test script looks like this;

```
module.exports = {
    'getting emails...': function (browser) {
        browser.getInboxEmails();
    },

    'bfs': function (browser) {
        browser.url('https://www.motorcyclenews.com/bikes-for-sale/****');
        
        *...assertions, etc*

    },

    'closing the browser': function (browser) {
       browser.browserEnd();
    },
};
```

When I run this nightwatchjs script, the following is outputted;

[image]

however, the browser doesn't close.

I kind of expected this, as in my getInboxEmails command script included;

```
            //  mailListener.on('server:disconnected', function() {
            //  });

            //  mailListener.stop();
```

However, when I uncommented these two commands, I didn't get the number of emails displayed (but the test/browser correctly 'shut down'.

So the output was now;

[image]

So it appears that the number of emails is correctly displayed when the disconnect and stop are omitted, but the test doesn't cease.

And when the disconnect and stop are added, the number of emails is not displayed but the test finishes correctly.

And what I'd like to do is list the number of emails and for the test to end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to init your mail listener in beforeAll part

and stop that in afterAll

the problem in your example is that your stop is reached in the init part so your mailbox listener will never be raised

```
    mailListener.on('mailbox', function(mailbox) {
            var totalInboxMessages = (mailbox.messages.total);
            console.log('Total number of Inbox emails: ', totalInboxMessages);
        });
```

Just do some staff as below

```
let mailListener ;
jest.beforeAll(() => {
     mailListener = new MailListener({
            username: '#########@outlook.com',
            password: '#########',
            host: 'imap-mail.outlook.com',
            port: 993,
            tls: true,
            connTimeout: 10000,
            authTimeout: 5000,
            tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
            mailbox: 'Inbox', 
            searchFilter: ['ALL'], 
            markSeen: true,
            fetchUnreadOnStart: false,
            attachments: false,
        });

        mailListener.start();

        mailListener.on('server:connected', function() {});

        mailListener.on('mailbox', function(mailbox) {
            var totalInboxMessages = (mailbox.messages.total);
            console.log('Total number of Inbox emails: ', totalInboxMessages);
        });
});
```

and finally in the end part of your tests

```
jest.afterAll(() => {
    mailListener.stop();
});
```

wish this help